# i want google play store like scrollview

Tags: android, json, layout

I need the play store like scroll view horizontal view but i cannot able to achieve it.

I had tried this code if possible please provide a link also.

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <HorizontalScrollView 
   android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:fillViewport="true"
   android:scrollbars="horizontal" >
<GridView
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:columnWidth="300dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal">
</GridView>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want this type of View in my app please check screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use RecylerView for this.

```
 LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());    
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);

    RecylerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

Comment: how do I repeat it multiple times so that I can have multiple horizontal recyclers for different categories, I have tried possible combinations but with no result

Comment: if i could totally got what you meant then you must use gridlayoutmanager to achive it @89n3ur0n

Answer (score 2):

**Add this to your app's build.gradle file**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'mobi.parchment:parchment:1.6.9@aar'
```

}

**Here is the listView**

```
<mobi.parchment.widget.listview.ListView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:parchment="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/<YOUR PACKAGE NAME>"
android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="< horizontal | vertical >"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="< true | false >"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="< true | false >"
android:clipToPadding="< true | false >"
parchment:isViewPager="< true | false >"
parchment:orientation="< horizontal | vertical >"
parchment:cellSpacing="10dp"
parchment:isCircularScroll="< true | false >"
parchment:snapPosition="< center | start | end | onScreen >"
parchment:snapToPosition="< true | false >" />
```

**Well you may try checking this out** https://github.com/EmirWeb/parchment